# Mousedown event not fired on a Div if the Div is placed on top of an img tag - issue is only in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I have placed a Div on top of an img tag. In my example the Div with cls 'justForClickCls' is placed on top of an img which is wrapped in another div 'gameBoardElementGreyCls'. The mousedown on the 'justForClickCls' div is not firing in IE. However it works in every other browser.

Here is the code. Any help is much appreciated. By the way i'm testing it i IE 9

```
<div class='gameBoardElementCls'>
    <div id='9' class='justForClickCls' style='z-index:10;position:absolute;margin:20px;width:80px;height:80px;'></div>
    <div class='gameBoardElementGreyCls'><img src='img/greygmelement.png' width='110px' height='110px'></img></div>
</div>

<script>
    $("div.justForClickCls").mousedown(function () {
        alert('clicked 1');
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

In my case setting opacity to zero is not a valid solution since the div has other elements that would become invisible.
This solved the problem. Add the following to the div style:
background-image:url('.');

Answer (score 2):

Got stuck with the same problems for hours and user983327's last comment saved my day: IE required me to set a background color for the element to work.

Setting the opacity to 0 then achieved the same result as having a transparent background and made the whole thing cross browsers compatible.

Comment: Thank you guys for saving my day! Writing the two CSS rules fixed it: `opacity: 0; background-color: white;`

Answer (score 0):

First thing you should fix is the closing tag in the img

```
<img src='img/greygmelement.png' width='110px' height='110px'></img>
```

To

```
<img src='img/greygmelement.png' width='110px' height='110px' />
```

Next, *mousedown* seems unnecessary since you are trying to trap the click. Simple use `click` instead of `mousedown`.

Now check this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8zFzP/) of you coding, which **is working**

Comment: Thanks for the response. I fixed the img tag but the mousedown still didn't work on the other div. I'm building a board game and hence its necessary to track the mourdown and muoseup and hover events. And moreover I need the event to be fired on the other div as its exactly positioned to where I want the events to be listening rather than in the entire image.

Comment: @user983327, Did you see the demo, it is working in on IE 9 to.

Comment: I checked the demo of the code. It works in every browser. In IE it works only when I click on the text. However if I remove the text its not working.

Comment: @user983327, of course, it needs either block element or clickable element to trigger the event.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I added a white background color and made the opacity to 0 to trick the browser to think it has a clickable element and it worked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: 'click' event fires after mouseup, so won't work for those who need to capture the event as soon as mouse button is clicked down but before it is released